# Disable the Grid vertical scroll-behavior of the scrollviewer in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

**Grid Structure**

Load

[image]

When click on textbox and open keypad then title scroll up..I want to fix the title place (not scroll)

[image]

how to resove this problem?

when click on textbox keypad opened but title scroll up...

**My xaml code**

```
<Grid x:Name="grdEmergencyServices" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled" >
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/1.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="500*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Border Background="#8C6446" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0" Background="#8C6446" Opacity="0.8">
            <TextBlock Name="pageTitle" Text="Title Name" Style="                                                                   {StaticResource CommonStyle}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
    <ProgressRing Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ProgressRingLoad" Visibility="Collapsed" Background="Transparent" IsActive="True" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Margin="20">
        <TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Margin="0,500,0,0"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I can't see the photos you've added. Could you describe the problem in text?

Comment: Yes... you are also see my xaml code..when click on textbox grid scroll up and Titlebar scroll up and not visible... so how to fix titlename.

Comment: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/24175.windows-phone-keyboard-prevent-page-screen-scrolling-up-when-soft-keyboard-is-opened-c-xaml.aspx